# How to display JSON data in HTML based on logged in user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a form in which user logs in and the data gets saved in a JSON dynamically. All that is working, but I want only that JSON data to be displayed which contains the email id of the logged in user which is set in session.
Here is the script which creates the JSON:
`

```
var g_objJSON = [];

        /** setJSON - Create JSON object
        * Returns - Nothing
        **/
    function setJSON() {
        //alert($(this).data('session-name'));
            var v_aJSON = [];
            var v_hObject = {};
            var v_hTempHash = {};

            var v_sKey = '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])) ? $_SESSION['userEmail'] : ''; ?>';
            console.log(v_sKey);
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('product-description')
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

                    var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
                    if(selectedEl){
                        //selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
                    }
                    //this.classList.add("selected");
                    alert('in addEventListener: ' + $(this).data('name'));
                    var v_sValue = $(this).data('name');
                    alert('event name : ' + v_sValue);
                    try {
                        v_hObject[v_sKey] = v_sValue;
                        if (g_objJSON == undefined) {
                            v_aJSON.push(v_hObject);
                        } else {
                            v_hTempHash = mergeHashOb(g_objJSON[0], v_hObject);
                            v_aJSON.push(v_hTempHash);
                        }
                        g_objJSON = v_aJSON;
                        alert("Events JSON created!");
                        for (var item in g_objJSON[0]) {
                            console.log("Email: " + item + "\nLocation: " +   g_objJSON[0][item]);
                            $.ajax({
                            url: 'json-2.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {json: JSON.stringify(g_objJSON)},
                            dataType: 'json'
                        });
                        }

                    } catch (x) {
                            alert(x.message);
                    }
                }, false);;
            }
    }
    /** mergeHashOb - Merge a new JSON object with the global JSON object
               * @prm_hObj - Existing Hash object
               * @prm_hObj2 - New Hash object
               * Returns - A new Hash object contains the merged Hash objects
               **/
               function mergeHashOb(prm_hObj, prm_hObj2) {
                       var v_hObj = {};
                       for (var item in prm_hObj) { 
                               v_hObj[item] = prm_hObj[item]; 
                       }
                       for (var item in prm_hObj2) { 
                               v_hObj[item] = prm_hObj2[item]; 
                       }
                       return v_hObj;
               }
```

`

json-2.php:
`

```
<?php
    // let's parse this right away
    $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

    /* sanity check */
    if ($json != null)
    {
      // parse the file contents to json
      $fileContents = file_get_contents('event_data.json');
      $parsedJson = json_decode($fileContents);

      if ($parsedJson === null) {
        // it's either the file contains bad json or it is empty (tested with 7.1)
        $parsedJson = array();
      }

      // append your new data to the parsed json
      // I'm assuming the $_POST['json'] returns a stringified array, I'll take the first element and append it.
      $parsedJson[] = $json[0];
      // now write to the file
      $file = fopen('event_data.json','w'); // note that we're writing, not appending.
      // write to file the json_encoded $parsedJson
      fwrite($file, json_encode($parsedJson));
      fclose($file);
    }
    else
    {
      // handle the error 
    }
?>
```

`

event_data.json:
`[{"charlie@gmail.com":"Finding Accomodation"},{"charlie@gmail.com":"Money Matters"},{"charlie@gmail.com":"Pathways to Deakin"},{"_empty_":"Finding Accomodation"},{"vrishty.garg@deakin.edu.au":"Finding Accomodation"},{"vrishty.garg@deakin.edu.au":"Finding Accomodation"},{"charlie@gmail.com":"Finding Accomodation"}]`

So, I want only those arrays displayed which contains the key as logged in user, say charlie@gmail.com at a time, not all of the above.

Function of creating table:
`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //alert('inside document.ready');
  $.getJSON("event_data.json", function (data) {
    //alert('in each function of getJSON()');

                    var arrItems = [];      // THE ARRAY TO STORE JSON ITEMS.
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                      arrItems.push(value);       // PUSH THE VALUES INSIDE THE ARRAY.
                    });

                    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR TABLE HEADER.
                   var col = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
                        for (var key in arrItems[i]) {
                            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                                col.push(key);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                    //var button = document.createElement("button");

                    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

                    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

                    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                        th.innerHTML = col[i];
                        tr.appendChild(th);
                    }

                    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {

                        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                            tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[i][col[j]];
                        }
                    }

                    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
                    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
                    //divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                    divContainer.appendChild(table);
                    //divContainer.appendChild(button);
                });
});
```

`

Comment: That's a lot of code.

Comment: You should try any php framework, as Laravel, Synfony, CodeIgniter...

Comment: I just want a check in the function of creating table above to check for a particular id whichever is logged in.

Comment: I just want a check in the function of creating table above to check for a particular id whichever is logged in.